# How to detect if running Arduino or bare Atmega328p?

Tags: frequency

I'm building something that will mostly run on bare ATmega328p at 8 MHz (as described eg. [**here**](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11637)), but sometimes I need to run the same code on an Arduino.

I need to **[initialize the DHT library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino#L21)** depending on the clock frequency. For simplicity, I'd rather detect the running environment runtime, in the program itself.

So, is there a straightforward way to detect the clock speed (from fuses?) or some other difference between a stock UNO board and a bare ATmega328p using the internal 8 MHz clock?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you using the internal clock of the ATmega on an Arduino board?

Comment: Actually one thing I want this for is to test how the clock frequency (among other things) affects the RF range.

Comment: is `F_CPU` set? im wondering if you can read that

Answer (score 3):

Bare vs Stock is nearly impossible to detect at compile time. Where it depends on what you think you are trying to determine versus detect.

The best I can think of is creating a different Board definition; one for your bare and the other being the stock (i.g. UNO). Where now in IDE 1.5 see [github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/…](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5---3rd-party-Hardware-specification) the parameter uno.build.board=AVR_UNO, which provides is used to set a compile-time variable ARDUINO_{build.board} to allow use of conditional code between #ifdefs. So you can create bare board definition with e.g. bare.build.board=MY_BARE and then have some #ifdef's for ARDUINO_MY_BARE

Otherwise wrap some #ifdef's around F_CPU as @sechleen points out. This is viable and done often in the core libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to distinguish your bare AVR from the arduino board at run time is to build the bare AVR board with a distinguishing feature - such as a known
voltage on one of the D/A ports - that won't be present on your Arduino.